# creating random salt with php's crypt

Tags: php, crypt

Usally we use `mt_rand` to create a random salt to use it with `crypt()`. 
But according to `mt_rand` manual page on php's site "not be used for cryptographic purposes[...]consider using openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() instead." Also, at `crypt` manual page on php's site, someone suggest to use the

```
mcrypt_create_iv
```

So, to test them, I took [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php#105949) crypt's wrapper and change the following line

```
$salt .= substr("./ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789", mt_rand(0, 63), 1);

//change it to
$salt .= substr("./ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789", openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(63, $cstrong), 50); 

$salt .= substr("./ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789", mcrypt_create_iv(63, MCRYPT_RAND), 50); 

$salt .= substr("./ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789", mt_srand(), 1);
```

Then I commented all the lines except one and start running the code, to check each function. I refreshed my page and the validation works fine. But when I run `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` or `mcrypt_create_iv` I see the same hash frequently.

```
$2y$08$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$.UrC6Lo4LNk8iLmoi25KEoVzHHTK7tNC
```

I saw the above hash like 10 times.

When I use  `mt_srand` the hash never changes at all.

I test the same functions in another, simpler wrapper, found [here](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/blowfish-crypt/#section_2) and they act the same as I described above.

I am a begginer with hashing and `crypt`. I'm confused, what should I actually use?

Answer (score 2):

Using `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` is about the best you can do in php to get random bytes. 
I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the `substr()`, as `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` returns bytes, not an offset.

To clarify, you could use `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64)` on its own to generate a 64 byte salt.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I just noticed that difference. I'll study more and let you know..

Comment: Using just the `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64)` sounds good, but I can't use it with `sprintf` because the former produces bytes and the latter is about string. So I cant include something like `$2y$` in my hash, wich "stands" for blowfish. Also I can't think of a way to check hashed password and input password...

Comment: Just chuck the (already random) data into a hash.. e.g. **sha1(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64))**  Does that help?

Comment: Also, if you're randomly salting passwords, you'll need to store the salt along side the hashed password in the database in order to recalculate the hash.  If this is specifically about passwords, you shouldn't be storing them with a reversible hash eg. blowfish.